# TypeScript Suggested keys in object

Tags: typescript

I would like to define a TypeScript type, which would suggest (preferred) object keys in editor, but I do not want to restrict user to define arbitrary keys.

So I have defined following type:

```js
type SuggestedProperties = 'click' | 'change' | 'blur' | string;
```

These are preferred properties: `'click' | 'change' | 'blur'` (but I do want to allow arbitrary `string`.)

```js
type SuggestedKeysType = Partial<{ [key in SuggestedProperties]: any }>;
```

Now I want the editor to tell me about these: `'click' | 'change' | 'blur'` in the first place.

Is it possible? Is my example correct?
Visual Studio Code / [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-suggested-union-type?file=index.ts):

[image]

Comment: Your stackblitz link is broken. External links and images, while nice supplements, are not substitutes for plaintext code; please consider adding all relevant as plaintext.

Comment: Note that in a [mapped type](//www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html) like `{[K in XXX]: YYY}`, the `K` is a *type parameter* and thus conventions would have it be a single uppercase letter, or at least start with an uppercase letter.  Writing `{[key in XXX]: YYY}` is unconventional for that reason.  Mapped types are similar to but distinct from [index signatures](//www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#index-signatures) of the form `{[k: XXX]: YYY}` where `k` is a *dummy key name*, and key names are conventionally written with an initial lowercase letter.

Comment: (Hence, `{[key in SuggestedProperties]: any}` is unconventional and best replaced with something like `{[K in SuggestedProperties]: any}` or `{[Key in SuggestedProperties]: any}`)

Comment: @jcalz I have fixed the stackblitz link and have taken into account your suggestions. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you add `| string` to `SuggestedProperties`, then the entire type will be eagerly reduced to just `string`.  All the `string` [literal types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/literal-types.html) will be absorbed in the union, and then the compiler and your IDE will have forgotten all about them:

```
type Oops = 'a' | 'b' | string;
// type Oops = string
```

Instead you should make your `SuggestedKeysType` a type with both known keys and a [string index signature](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#index-signatures), possibly like this:

```
type SuggestedProperties = 'click' | 'change' | 'blur';

type SuggestedKeysType = { [K in SuggestedProperties]?: any } & { [k: string]: any }
```

Then you get the suggestions you expect:

```
const myObject: SuggestedKeysType = {
  foo: 1,
  bar: 2,
  click: 3,
  // Suggestions here:
  // ☐ blur, (property) blur?: any
  // ☐ change, (property) change?: any
}
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBA8g9mAzlAvFA5AQ3VAPhgIx30WACcBLAOwHMBuAKAHompRJYFk1TLaGG7aAGUArjRoRSEACYAFMgghlgFKagwBjADYVNAa2JaAFploQj6AttFl0jQeBHjJ0mQGkIIRABUnGgG8oAG13KGooMQkpYFkFJRU1RABdAH4ALigzECgAXygAMigg4P1M3moaZMzsvIFNOCpSKABbEBgCACsITWBMqNdYjy9ffzQAhigoADM4OEyARgAaSagCTDJMgCYVqZ09MqgAZl2oFkiXGIpG5GNlCHTV88AEMjWbMiWoAAowRUgVEAASjetgyWSoICerFemlM5k+Pz+ylAwNhZkkYOyDFyQA)

Comment: Thank your for recommendation and explanation.

Answer (score 1):

I dont know if exists any better solution but this way works:

```
type MyObj = Partial<
  {
    [key in SuggestedProperties]: any;
  } & {
    [index: string]: any;
  }
>;
```

autocomplete will suggest SuggestedProperties first and you will can pass any other property